# Absolute Convergence of the Improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{-4-\epsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+3x-4)x}dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

I need to prove that the following improper integral converges absolutely, and I don't know how:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-4-\epsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{(x^2+3x-4)x}dx$$

where $\epsilon$ is a small number (because the function diverges in x=-4)

Any help?

Comment: This still has the singularity $x=0$ inside the interval of convergence.

Comment: You just need to check out if the absolute value of the integrand is integrable : since $\epsilon$ is non-negative, there is no problem for the highest value of $x$. The infinity is not a problem too (see why). But there is a root of the polynomial $x^{2}+3x-4=\left(x-1\right)\left(x+4\right) $ in the domain of the integration, and also $x=0$...

Comment: Sorry, I copied it wrong. That's OK. Now, how can I do it?

Comment: You can say that$\left|\frac{\cos\left(x\right)}{x\left(x-1\right)\left(x+4\right)}\right|$ is equivalent at the infinity to$\frac{1}{\left|x\right|^{3}}$, which is integrable.
Edit: actually, is your question what happens when $\epsilon\rightarrow0
 $ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{-4-\varepsilon}\frac{\cos x\,dx}{x(x-1)(x+4)}\,dx =\int_{-\infty}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{\cos (x-4)\,dx}{x(x-4)(x-5)}=-\int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos (x+4)\,dx}{x(x+4)(x+5)}$$
Now if $x\geq\varepsilon$ we have $\left|\cos x\right|\leq 1$ and $0\leq \frac{1}{x(x+4)(x+5)}\leq \frac{1}{x^3}$, where:
$$ \int_{\varepsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^3}=\frac{1}{2\varepsilon^2}.$$